# Azure cloud publish not uploading new files

Tags: azure, permissions, windows-8, cloud, publish

I've recently copied my visual studio 2010 website project from my windows 7 PC to a new PC running windows 8. That all went relatively smoothly. When I now publish or package the cloud project it only packages files that were originally on the windows 7 PC. Any files that I have created  on the windows 8 PC are ignored. The solution builds fine and I can run and debug the project fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that somewhere along the way the cloud project got disassociated with the web project so wasn't actually updating the file list for publishing - it was just using the file list that had already been generated on my old PC.

The fix was to scrap the cloud project and start over with a new one, then add a new web role to it and then convert that web role into a web application project and then move my whole existing website into that...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that would be, but here's something to try: In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-click the solution and choose Clean Solution. Then try to package/publish again.

Answer (score 0):

When you say files do you mean images/JavaScript?

What is the setting of the "Copy to Output Directory" ? for the files/content that is not making it...make sure it is **NOT** set to "Do not copy"

Are you using the new v1.8 of the SDK? (did you upgrade your project?)...this can happen if you are using an old SDK from a previous computer and then try to build stuff using a "fresh installation".